# How to make consistent Tabbing behavior across browser for disabled element

Tags: html, browser, tabbing

The behavior of the Tab key in different browser is different . In case of IE the focus is not going to a disabled tag,but  in case of FF and chrome the focus is going to the same.

```html
<html>
  <div disabled="disabled">
    <h1 tabindex="0">Hello Disabled Div</h1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1 tabindex="0">Hello 2</h1>
  </div>
</html>
```

Any idea how to make the FF and Chrome focus to the h1 when the div surrounding is having attribute `disabled="disabled"`?

Comment: `focus to the h1 when the div surrounding is having attribute disabled="disabled"` do you mean **not** focus?